# \dagger (amsbook) does not print after invocation of ibycus4

Tags: math-mode

The following causes the single dagger only to fail to print.

```
\documentclass{amsbook} 
\usepackage{ibycus4}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\begin{document}
\begin{theorem}
\begin{align*}\tag{$\dagger$}\label{formula}
7 + 5 = 12
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}\tag{$\ddagger$}\label{formula1}
7 + 5 = 13
\end{align*}
\ref{formula} and \ref{formula1} are both false.
\end{theorem}
\end{document}
```

I tried `\let\dagger\undefined` (and several variations of it) after `\usepackage{ibycus4}` but that blocked compilation.  Thanks for your consideration.

Comment: What fonts are being used? (Examine the PDF properties in your PDF reader.)

Comment: unrelated to dagger but never use `align*` for  one line equations that can have no alignment

Answer (score 3):

You can restore the original definition:

```
\documentclass{amsbook} 
\usepackage{ibycus4}
\def\dagger{\mathchar"2279}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\begin{document}
\begin{theorem}
\begin{align*}\tag{$\dagger$}\label{formula}
7 + 5 = 12
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}\tag{$\ddagger$}\label{formula1}
7 + 5 = 13
\end{align*}
\ref{formula} and \ref{formula1} are both false.
\end{theorem}
\end{document}
```

Comment: That works.  Thanks to all and to @Marijn in particular.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you don't just lose `\dagger`. You're completely giving up with every UTF-8 character and are essentially only allowed to use ASCII.

But the document is yours…

Use `\textdagger` and `\textdaggerdbl`, instead: tags are textual. You can also save the math definition of `\dagger` before loading `ibycus4` (I see no reason for loading it, nowadays).

```
\documentclass{amsbook}

\NewCommandCopy{\latexdagger}{\dagger}
\usepackage{ibycus4}
\NewCommandCopy{\sdagger}{\dagger}
\RenewCommandCopy{\dagger}{\latexdagger}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}
\begin{align*}\tag{\textdagger}\label{formula}
7 + 5 = 12+\dagger
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}\tag{\textdaggerdbl}\label{formula1}
7 + 5 = 13
\end{align*}
\eqref{formula} and \eqref{formula1} are both false.
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

[image]